# How do I build and install the gspca webcam driver?

Tags: webcam

I tried to install gspca to run Orite webcam on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, but I failed.

It lost a lot of headers, here are my instructions but failed.

```
  wget http://mxhaard.free.fr/spca50x/Download/gspcav1-20071224.tar.gz
  tar zxvf gspcav1-20071224.tar.gz
  cd gspcav1-20071224/
  sudo ./gspca_build
  sudo touch /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic/include/linux/config.h
  sudo mkdir /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic/include/asm
  sudo touch /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic/include/asm/semaphore.h
  sudo touch /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic/include/linux/videodev.h
  sudo touch /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic/include/linux/smp_lock.h
```

How to solve it?

---

I move to `/usr/src` and make:

```
  sam@sam:/usr/src/gspcav1-20071224$ sudo make
  make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build SUBDIRS=/usr/src/gspcav1-20071224       CC=cc modules
  make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic'
    CC [M]  /usr/src/gspcav1-20071224/gspca_core.o
  /usr/src/gspcav1-20071224/gspca_core.c:37:26: fatal error: linux/config.h: No       such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[2]: *** [/usr/src/gspcav1-20071224/gspca_core.o] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/src/gspcav1-20071224] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic'
  make: *** [default] Error 2
  sam@sam:/usr/src/gspcav1-20071224$
```

Answer (score 2):

I Have found the solution in 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1746591

Do like this

```
/* 
#ifndef AUTOCONF_INCLUDED
#include <linux/config.h> 
#endif
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wget http://mxhaard.free.fr/spca50x/Download/gspcav1-20071224.tar.gz
sudo mv gspcav1-20071224.tar.gz /usr/src
cd /usr/src
sudo tar zxvf gspcav1-20071224.tar.gz
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential make automake autoconf g++ gcc
sudo apt-get remove --purge gspca*
cd gspcav1-20071224
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -ae
sudo modprobe gspca
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and when make it shows errors. How to solve it? Thank you~

Comment: Same errors as the ones in your question?

Comment: Yes,I revised my original post with the last message after following your instuctions. And it's the same with my original instructions. So I try to touch header file but failed.

Comment: my error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory